# Render a part of list in Model mvc3

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model, lazy-loading

I have list questions (about 1000 questions in a Model).
I want to render 100 questions first on view after user scroll down will render 100 next questions.

Do you know how to make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for an infinite scroll implementation of which there are many

I'd probably look to [Rob Conery's blog on scroll just in time](http://wekeroad.com/2009/11/27/paging-records-sucks--use-jquery-to-scroll-just-in-time) first, which he calls bottomless scrolling.   It uses jquery and basically fires an ajax request for more based on a height calculation while you scroll.

but there are many more examples [Infinitescroll](http://infinitescroll.codeplex.com/), [Infinite scroll with mvc4](http://www.gavindraper.co.uk/2012/05/10/infinite-scroll-with-asp-net-mvc-4/), [Infinite scroll with mvc](http://tpeczek.blogspot.ie/2012/04/infinite-scroll-in-aspnet-mvc.html)...

Answer (score 0):

you have to program some ajax call through javascript to show new rows, and then use this javascript code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if (document.documentElement.clientHeight + $(document).scrollTop() >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        getCities(10);
    }
});
```

and here you have an example method:

```
function getCities(count) {
     $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetCities")", { term: $("#search").val(), start: $("#cities tbody tr").length, count: count }, function (data, status, req) {
        if (data.count != 0) {
            $.each(data.cities, function() { 
                $("#cities tbody").append("<tr data-id='" + cityid + "' data-state='" + stateid + "'><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + state + "</td></tr>");
            });
        }
    });
}
```